# Understanding Python Pickle Insecurity

Tags: python, security, namespaces, pickle

It states in the Python documentation that `pickle` is not secure and shouldn't parse untrusted user input.  If you research this; almost all examples demonstrate this with a `system()` call via `os.system`.

Whats not clear to me, is how `os.system` is interpreted correctly without the `os` module being imported.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.loads("cos\nsystem\n(S'ls /'\ntR.") # This clearly works.
bin  boot  cgroup  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
0
>>> dir() # no os module
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'pickle']
>>> os.system('ls /')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>>>
```

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name of the module (`os`) is part of the opcode, and `pickle` automatically imports the module:

```
# pickle.py
def find_class(self, module, name):
    # Subclasses may override this
    __import__(module)
    mod = sys.modules[module]
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
    return klass
```

Note the `__import__(module)` line.

The function is called when the `GLOBAL 'os system'` pickle bytecode instruction is executed.

This mechanism is necessary in order to be able to unpickle instances of classes whose modules haven't been explicitly imported into the caller's namespace.

Answer (score 9):

For altogether too much information on writing malicious Pickles that go much further than the standard os.system() example, see this [presentation](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Slaviero/BH_US_11_Slaviero_Sour_Pickles_Slides.pdf) and its accompanying [paper](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Slaviero/BH_US_11_Slaviero_Sour_Pickles_WP.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

If you use pickletools.dis to disassemble the pickle you can see how this is working:

```
import pickletools
print pickletools.dis("cos\nsystem\n(S'ls ~'\ntR.")
```

Output:

```
 0: c    GLOBAL     'os system'
11: (    MARK
12: S        STRING     'ls ~'
20: t        TUPLE      (MARK at 11)
21: R    REDUCE
22: .    STOP
```

Pickle uses a simple stack-based virtual machine that records the instructions used to reconstruct the object. In other words the pickled instructions in your example are:

Push self.find_class(module_name, class_name) i.e. push os.system
Push the string 'ls ~'
Build tuple from topmost stack items
Apply callable to argtuple, both on stack. i.e. os.system(*('ls ~',))

[Source](http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure)

Comment: Yes, but why does this not require `import os`?

Comment: dir() tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. When you import a module dynamically there's no guarantee you will see it with dir()

Answer (score 2):

Importing a module only adds it to the local namespace, which is not necessarily the one you're in. **Except when it doesn't:**

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> __import__('os')
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```