# How to convert a list into a string and then convert it back in python?

Tags: python, udp

I want to send a list through UDP/TCP, but since they support string list only, I need to convert the list into string and convert it back.

My list is like

```
['S1','S2','H1','C1','D8']
```

I know I can use

```
string_ = ''.join(list_)
```

to convert it into string.

But how to convert it back?

Or there is another way I can use UDP/TCP to send a list?

Comment: Does your list always contain strings, or can it contain objects of other types (and, if so, which types)?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use `pickle` as it is not secure: someone sending malicious input to your UDP/TCP server could run arbitrary code on your box. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302247/understanding-python-pickle-insecurity

Answer (score 3):

Custom format would depend on the assumptions about the list items format, so [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) looks like the safest way to go:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.dumps(['S1','S2','H1','C1','D8'])
>>> data
'["S1", "S2", "H1", "C1", "D8"]'
>>> json.loads(data)
[u'S1', u'S2', u'H1', u'C1', u'D8']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a separator:

```
string_ = ';'.join(list_)

list_ = string_.split(';')
```

You need to make sure the separator character can't be within your string. If it is, you might need encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could append a separator between the list elements and use it calling `split` to get the list back.

**EDIT:**

As *@Eric Fortin* mentionned in his answer, the separator should be something that cannot be in your string. One possibility is -- as he suggested -- to use encoding. Another possiblity is to send elements one by one, but that would obviously increase the communication overhead.

Note that your separator may be a sequence, it does not need to be one single character.

```
str_list = separator.join(list_)
new_list = str_list.split(separator)
```

If you know the format of your list elements, you may even go without using separators!

```
str_list = "".join(list_)
re.split(reg_exp, str_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have python on both ends of network communication, you can use [`dumps`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) and [`loads`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) functions from `pickle` module design especially for serializing python objects:

```
import pickle

a = ['S1','S2','H1','C1','D8']
string_ = pickle.dumps(a)

...

a = pickle.loads(string_)
```

Otherwise [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22502361/756261) proposed by *@bereal* is better one because there are json libraries for most programming languages. But it will demand some processing for data types not supported by json.

**EDIT**

As @bereal noticed there can be security problem with `pickle` because it's actually an executable language.

Comment: One problem with pickle and networking is that it's in fact an [executable language](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/playing-pickle-security/), so anyone can inject arbitrary code into the server side.