# How to send public key from server to client VIA socket using pickle

Tags: python, networking, pickle, public-key

I need help sending a public key from the server to client via socket using pickle. I run both just by opening two command prompts so I don't need to send it over a network or etc if it makes a difference. Just not sure how to make the public_key a pickle file and send it over socket.

Server code:

```
import socket
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
random_generator = Random.new().read
import pickle

def main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print "Connection from: "+str(addr)
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
    print "from connected user: "+str(data)
    data = str(data)
    #"Step 2 Server says hello and sends the public key certificate."        
    print "Start SSL Handshake"
    print"Press Enter to Generate the key pair."        
    a = raw_input("")
    key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
    public_key = key.publickey()        <----- need to pickle and send to client
    c.send(data)
```

Client code:

```
import socket
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
random_generator = Random.new().readdef main():

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))
#"Step 1 Client says hello."
message = raw_input("-> ")
while message != 'q':
    s.send(message)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print 'Received the public key from server: (iCrypto.PublicKey.RSA '
    #"Step 3 Client verifies the public key."  <------------ need to recieve / depickle key here
    message = raw_input("-> Press enter to verify the public key.")
```

Comment: Don't use pickle with sockets. This is a huge security risk.

Comment: TCP is a streaming connection. You need a protocol to send packaged data.

Comment: This is for a class, not really worried with security risk as the only thing being sent is a string.

Comment: `key.publickey().exportkey() -> bytes:` [source](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#exportKey). Honestly I'd skip pickling, and just send the raw `bytes` object over the socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pickling the output from an open port is asking for trouble ([understanding pickle insecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302247/understanding-python-pickle-insecurity)). Furthermore you're just adding a layer of complexity that isn't needed. [`RSA._RSAobj.exportKey`](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#exportKey) returns a `bytes` object which can be sent directly over a socket, and is conveniently also exactly the data type needed for [`RSA.importKey()`](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#importKey).

Server:

```
#conn is your socket
conn.send(key.publickey().exportKey(format='PEM', passphrase=None, pkcs=1))
```

Client:

```
#you'll need to decide how to determine N: number of bytes received (should be constant for constant size key)
pub_key = RSA.importKey(conn.recv( N ), passphrase=None)
```

Comment: Mine is c and s not conn. So should this work? c.send(key.publickey().exportKey(format='PEM', passphrase=None, pkcs=1)) and public_key = RSA.importKey(s.recv(1024), passphrase=None)

Comment: @rippleEffect Whenever I post code I change it slightly to discourage copy-paste. The goal is understanding rather than a quick fix.

Comment: @rippleEffect from my testing `len(key.publickey().exportKey()) == 271` when the a 1024 bit key is used. "PEM" is supposed to be a standardized format, but it's possible it may be beneficial to double check each time.

Comment: I'm not getting an error, but it stops the program once it gets the the public_key = line on the client side

Comment: @rippleEffect That sounds like a different problem then. you should break down you program into its key components to find out why it's stopping. If you get stuck and it's a separate problem, you should ask it as a separate question on the site.